# Связь сервисов в docker-compose

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

Я новичок в docker. У меня есть 2 спринг бут сервиса:
1 admin-server приложение на основе спринг админ. Порт 9003
2 client-service простое спринг бут приложение с парой эндпойнтов. Порт 8080

Я создал в каждом проекте dockerfile. Листинг:

1.Админ application.properties:

```
server.port = 9003
```

Админ докерфайл:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine3.12
COPY build/libs/admin-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar admin-server.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/admin-server.jar"]
EXPOSE 9003
```

2.Клиент application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://admin-server:9003
spring.boot.admin.api-path=/instances


info.application.name=client-service
info.application.description=spring boot client-service application
info.application.version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Клиент докерфайл:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine3.12
COPY build/libs/client-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar client-server.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/client-server.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

И собственно docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  admin-server:
    image: amerta90/admin-server
    container_name: admin-server
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 9003:9003

  client-service:
    image: amerta90/client-service
    container_name: client-service
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - admin-server
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Все хорошо поднимается, даже работает) Но проблема в том, что админ не видит клиентское приложение. Вот такой варнинг возвращает:

```
client-service    | 2022-05-05 09:29:49.205  WARN 1 --- [gistrationTask1] d.c.b.a.c.r.ApplicationRegistrator       : Failed to register application as Application(name=spring-boot-application, managementUrl=http://1159d8a4d93f:8080/
actuator, healthUrl=http://1159d8a4d93f:8080/actuator/health, serviceUrl=http://1159d8a4d93f:8080/) at spring-boot-admin ([http://localhost:9003/instances]): I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:9003/instances": Connectio
n refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused). Further attempts are logged on DEBUG level
```

Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localhost внутри контейнера и на хосте (в данном случае на ПК) - это разные адреса ([What does localhost means inside a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278632/what-does-localhost-means-inside-a-docker-container)).

Варианты решения:

1. Создать сеть и подключить в нее оба контейнера. [Networking overview](https://docs.docker.com/network/).
2. Обратиться из контейнера к localhost ПК и через него ко второму контейнеру.   [I want to connect from a container to a service on the host](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds).
3. Прокинуть link между контейнерами. Эта возможность помечена как deprecated.  [Links](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/).

Первый вариант предпочтительный. Пример:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  admin-server:
    image: amerta90/admin-server
    container_name: admin-server
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 9003:9003
    networks:
      - my-network

  client-service:
    image: amerta90/client-service
    container_name: client-service
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - admin-server
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: "bridge"
```

Здесь мы создаем сеть с именем **my-network** и подключаем в нее контейнеры.
После этого внутри сети можно обращаться к контейнеру по его имени. Соответственно, вместо **localhost** нужно использовать **admin-server**.

Comment: Спасибо за вашу помощь, к сожалению в моем случае пока это не помогло

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Просто надо было пересобрать jar'ник

Comment: Строку подключения предлагаю вынести в конфигурационный файл. Тогда не потребуется пересобирать приложение и можно будет разделить конфигурации для разных окружений. И кстати еще с этой статьей [Networking with standalone containers](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/) можно поэкспериментировать для более полного понимания.