# Обновление MySQL базы Docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер, docker, docker-compose

Ранее не работал с `Docker` и еще не до конца понимаю принцип его работы.

В контейнере на докере я запустил `mysql` сервер, `phpmyadmin` и `metabase`.

База MySQL, которая находится в `/var/lib/mysql` постоянно обновляется, но в `Docker` это хранится в отдельном каталоге, по пути: `/var/lib/docker/volumes/metabase_dbdata/_data`

При перезапуске `Docker` командой `docker-compose up -d` он не обновляет базу в `/var/lib/docker/volumes/metabase_dbdata/_data`, а именно её я вижу в `PMA`.

Мне нужно, чтобы при каждом перезапуске (`docker-compose up -d`) он сопостовлял данные из `/var/lib/docker/volumes/metabase_dbdata/_data` с данными из `/var/lib/mysql` и обновлял их

Возможно, я неправильно понял принцип работы `Docker` или использую не ту команду?

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ####
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ###
      MYSQL_USER: ####
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ###
    ports:
      - "6033:3306"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      MB_SITE_URL: http://localhost:8081/pma/
  metabase:
    image: metabase/metabase:latest
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3025:3025"
    volumes:
      - data:/metabase
    environment:
      MB_SITE_URL: http://localhost:3000/metabase/

volumes:
  dbdata:
  data:
```

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, текст docker-compose.

Comment: Готово, добавил

Answer (score 0):

Здесь [Связь сервисов в docker-compose](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406785/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-docker-compose) есть варианты того, как можно объединить docker-контейнеры в сеть. Если объединять контейнеры через links, то у metabase тоже должна быть ссылка на БД. И для links и для network обращение к другому контейнеру выполняется по доменному имени (имени контейнера) и порту, например, phpmyadmin:80.

Соответственно, нужно связать metabase с mysql, например так:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dbmetabaserootpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: metabase
      MYSQL_USER: metabase
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: metabasedatabasepassword
    ports:
      - 6033:3306
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
      
  metabase:
    image: metabase/metabase:latest
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    volumes:
      - data:/metabase
    environment:
      MB_DB_TYPE: mysql
      MB_DB_DBNAME: metabase
      MB_DB_PORT: 3306
      MB_DB_USER: metabase
      MB_DB_PASS: metabasedatabasepassword
      MB_DB_HOST: db
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

volumes:
  dbdata:
  data:
```

P.S. Пример переменных окружения взял отсюда [Docker compose for metabase and mysql](https://gist.github.com/knshiro/489d1e87bbe8e65d32bb54822752b78e), сам с metabase не работал.

Comment: Заметил, что не связал mysql с metabase, спасибо! Но тут другой вопрос, не в привязке, а в обновлении данных mysql. На локалке обновляются, а в контейнер обновления не переходят

Comment: Еще после перехода к metabase сначала пишет "Страница недоступна", но через пару секунд обновляется страница и идет бесконечная загрузка Metabase, но это уже к другому вопросу относится

Comment: Возможно, другую папку надо указать для metabase: - data:/metabase-data? Во всех примерах видел именно ее.